# Recursive find and replace based on regex

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I have changed up my director structure and I want to do the following:

- Do a recursive grep to find all instances of a match
- Change to the updated location string

One example (out of hundreds) would be:

```
from common.utils import debug  --> from etc.common.utils import debug
```

To get all the instances of what I'm looking for I'm doing:

```
$ grep -r 'common.' ./
```

However, I also need to make sure `common` is preceded by a space. How would I do this find and replace?

Comment: egrep is a Solaris command afaikr.

Comment: @RobKielty `egrep` is on at least all gnu systems, short for `grep -E` (extended regexes, which you actually don't need here)

Comment: Also, OP, you want `\.`, not just a `.`; otherwise it's interpreted as anything but a newline.

Comment: OP Can you call out exactly the change that you want to do? Will have to figure out the a sed command based on what you need done.

Comment: Actually `egrep` goes way back to Bell Labs original Unix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want because your refactoring example changes the import as well as the package, but the following will change `common. -> etc.common.` for all files in a directory:

```
sed -i 's/\bcommon\./etc.&/' $(egrep -lr '\bcommon\.' .)
```

This assumes you have gnu sed available, which most linux systems do.  Also, just to let you know, this will fail if there are too many files for sed to handle at one time.  In that case, you can do this:

```
egrep -lr '\bcommon\.' . | xargs sed -i 's/\bcommon\./etc.&/'
```

Note that it might be a good idea to run the sed command as `sed -i'.OLD' 's/\bcommon\./etc.&/'` so that you get a backup of the original file.

Answer (score 1):

This is roughly how you would do it using find. This requires testing

```
 find . -name \*.java -exec sed "s/FIND_STR/REPLACE_STR/g" {}
```

This translates as "Starting from the current directory find all files that end in .java and execute sed on the file (where {} is a place holder for the currently found file) "s/FIND_STR/REPLACE_STR/g" replaces FIND_STR with REPLACE_STR in each line in the current file.

Comment: Force of habit from vi. I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

If your `grep` implementation supports Perl syntax (`-P` flag, on e.g. Linux it's usually available), you can benefit from the additional features like word boundaries:

```
$ grep -Pr '\bcommon\.'
```

By the way:

`grep -r` tends to be much slower than a previously piped `find` command as in Rob's example. Furthermore, when you're sure that the file-names found do not contain any whitespace, using `xargs` is much faster than `-exec`:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.java' | xargs grep -P '\bcommon\.'
```

Or, applied to Tim's example:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.java' | xargs sed -i.bak 's/\<common\./etc.common./'
```

Note that, in the latter example, the replacement is done after creating a *.bak backup for each file changed. This way you can review the command's results and then delete the backups:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.bak' | xargs rm
```

If you've made an oopsie, the following command will restore the previous versions:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.bak' | while read LINE; do mv -f $LINE `basename $LINE`; done
```

Of course, if you aren't sure that there's no whitespace in the file names and paths, you should apply the commands via `find`'s `-exec` parameter.

Cheers!

Comment: You don't need `-P` for simple word boundaries, but they are `\<` for left and `\>` for right in `egrep`.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I figured after reading Tim's post. I tried it immediately in my `vi`. It worked, of course. Then I asked myself what I have done all those years. Now I don't know whether I should be happy about this new-to-me feature or crying about all the wasted time...

Comment: @tripleee egrep also supports `\b` for word boundaries.  `\<` and `\>` are just edge-specific versions of `\b`.